# Calculating the order of all the elements of the group $U(18)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have $U(18) = \{ \overline{1}, \overline{5}, \overline{7}, \overline{11}, \overline{13},\overline{17} \}$, the multiplicative group of integers modulo 18.

I'm required to find the order of each element.
Is there a way to calculate the orders or see if its infinite rather than calculating powers?

**Edit:**

Alright, I've calculated the orders:
\begin{align*}
o(\overline1) = 1\\
o(\overline5) = 6\\
o(\overline7) = 3\\
o(\overline{11}) = 6\\
o(\overline{13}) = 3\\
o(\overline{17}) = 2\\ \\ \\
\text{The powers:} \\ \\
1^1 &= 18\cdot0 + 1 \\
5^6 &= 15625 = 18\cdot868 + 1 \\
7^3 &= 343 = 18\cdot19 + 1\\
11^6 &= 1771561 = 18\cdot98420 + 1 \\
13^3 &= 2197 = 18 \cdot 122 + 1 \\
17^2 &= 289 = 18 \cdot 16 + 1 \\ \\
\end{align*}
Also we can say that this group is cyclic, ie:

\begin{align*}
5^1 &= 5 = 18\cdot0 + 5 \\
5^2 &= 25 = 18\cdot1 + 7 \\
5^3 &= 125 = 18\cdot6 + 17 \\
5^4 &= 625 = 18\cdot34 + 13 \\
5^5 &= 3125 = 18\cdot173 + 11 \\
5^6 &= 15625 = 18\cdot868 + 1 \\
\end{align*}

So $\langle\overline5\rangle = U(18)$

Comment: Nope: all you have to do is to compute powers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The powers of $5$ cover all elements and so there is no need to compute the powers of the other elements:
$$
\begin{align*}
5^2 &= 7 &\implies &o(7)=6/\gcd(2,6)=3 \\
5^3 &= 17 &\implies& o(17)=6/\gcd(3,6)=2 \\
5^4 &= 13 &\implies &o(13)=6/\gcd(4,6)=3 \\
5^5 &= 11 &\implies &o(11)=6/\gcd(5,6)=6\\
\end{align*}
$$